# Photoshop: the grid is on in every image I open, have to turn it off every time

Tags: adobe-photoshop, grid, photoshop-cs3

I activated Photoshop's grid via the keyboard shortcut, and now, every time I open an image (which wasn't necessarily saved with PS) has the grid on.
So now I have to turn the grid off for each and every image I open up in PS.
I tried closing the document window with the grid off, and quitting Ps with the grid off, but it doesn't go away.
This is hapening to me in MacOS, but did also happen in windows.

It's CS3.

The question is, how do I prevent this, and leave the grid off by default?

Comment: I can't seem to recreate this problem in Photoshop. Did you save any documents with Grid on? If so, try saving them with it off and see if that helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try starting Photoshop with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd> held down to reset Preferences to defaults (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> on Windows).

Comment: This. You probably have a corrupt preferences file. Unfortunately... as the answer suggests, you will loose ALL of your default settings.

Comment: @Joseph Redfern You mean you will lose all of your NON-default settings :)

Comment: Oops. Yes, that's what I mean :P

Comment: Yes! that was it. thanks! the conf file is plist, or otherwise readable? or is it binary? maybe next time I can change it by hand

Comment: @Petruza: I think the best idea would be to make a backup copy of the file once you have everything set up.  It's in `System> Preferences> Adobe Photoshop x Settings> Adobe Photoshop x Prefs`.

Comment: @paradroid: Don't know if you are refering to the same OS I have (MacOS 10.6) but I don't have such a path. I have `~/Library/Application Support/Adobe/Adobe Photoshop CS3/Presets` though.

Comment: @Petruza: Oh, I got that from a webpage and I assumed it was how you navigate to it in Finder.  The webpage was pretty old though, IIRC, as it mentioned Photoshop 6.0.

Comment: It looks like pre OSX, but thanks for the effort anyway!

Answer (score 3):

Instead of losing your Preferences, first try hitting Ctrl or Command + ' to disable the grid. THen, close Photoshop. Reopen and the grid should be off now.

Answer (score 2):

Go to properties icon at the right hand of your photoshop,click on rulers and grid, then proceed to click on the grid column.That should turn it off.
properties>rulers and grids>view grid.

Comment: Thanks @shedrack, I did know this 10 years ago when I asked the question, but Photoshop wouldn't remember the setting and always would turn the grids on again every time I started it up again.  
There's a solution that worked for me above, but ever since I've been using many different versions of Photoshop and hadn't had this problem anymore.

Answer (score 0):

command + '

keyboard shortcut for grid. Turns off the grid.

Comment: The original poster seems to know this, but the setting isn't sticking for them for some reason, so this doesn't answer the question.